# Deleting files and emptying trash using cron

Tags: cron, crontab

I'm new to making crontab files and I decided to try and make a job that would delete the contents of my Downloads folder, and then empty the trash. This is what I have:

```
0 9 * * *   rm $HOME/Downloads/*.*
10 9 * * *  rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Is this safe to run? I've heard a lot of talk on using the `rm` command wisely. Is it even necessary to remove the trash or does `rm` skip the trash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> Is this safe to run?

Depends on your definition of "save". It will not wreak havoc, but I wouldn't recommend it.

> ... does rm skip the trash?

The `rm` command skips the trash. `rm` doesn't even know about the concept of recycle bin. Virtually all command line commands have no idea about the concept of recycle bin (some oddballs think it is fun to have a terminal based recycle bin).

If you insist on a cron job to clear your download directory I would recommend doing it like this:

```
find $HOME/Downloads/ -mtime +1 -delete
```

This will delete all files (and directories) older than one day. Otherwise, if you downloaded something on 8:59, it will get deleted right away.

Note: under linux the wildcard `*.*` means something else than under windows. I assume you come from the windows world where `*.*` means every file.

Observe:

```
$ ls
foo  foo..bar  foo.bar  foo.bar.baz
$ echo *
foo foo..bar foo.bar foo.bar.baz
$ echo *.*
foo..bar foo.bar foo.bar.baz
$ echo *.*.*
foo..bar foo.bar.baz
$ echo *..*
foo..bar
```

`*` gets expanded to everything, including `.`, except a leading `.`, but that is an entirely different story. `*.*` gets expanded to everything which has at least one dot in the middle. `*.*.*` gets expanded to everything which has two dots. I think you get the idea, the dot doesn't have any special meaning in filename expansion. Be carefull though, the dot has a very special meaning when dealing with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), but that is also an entirely different story.

Comment: OH right, my bad. I've been using linux for a long time but I've never done much bash stuff. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll definitely use that.